# PowerShell: RunSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable is not setting variable

Tags: powershell, pipeline, runspace

**ConsoleApplication:**

```
class Program
{
    static void Main()
    {
        using (var runSpace = RunspaceFactory.CreateRunspace())
        {
            runSpace.Open();
            runSpace.SessionStateProxy.SetVariable("Var1", "Alex");
            using (var pipeline = runSpace.CreatePipeline("C:\\P.ps1"))
            {
                pipeline.Invoke();
            }
        }
    }
}
```

**P.ps1**

```
$logFile = "C:\MyLog.txt"

function Write-Log ([string] $message)
{
    Add-Content -Path $logFile -Value $message
}

Write-Log "Var1: " + $Var1
```

I expect "Var1: Alex" is written into my log file, but I get "Var1: ".

What did I wrong?

Edit:

My original problem is on the following site: http://nugetter.codeplex.com/workitem/31555

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Because of the space in write-log it sees them as multiple parameters.

Try this

```
Write-Log "Var1: $Var1"
```

Comment: First correct answer! Congratulation :) Unfurtunately I can only up vote one time.